# How to have a cycle in another scene on another script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to make a game where you get resources every few seconds, which spawn at different buildings. A truck drives around in a cycle to collect these resources. The thing is, I have to switch scenes because of the different buildings (which will all have their own scene, except for when someone has a better idea for that, then please comment it). I have no idea how I would get the exact location of the truck and how long it would take for the truck to get to the current buildings including driving, loading and unloading time. (The truck also shows up in the current buildings btw). Has anyone got any suggestions on how to do this? Can I run the cycle in the background somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don’t see why different scenes. You could make different areas in the same scene. It seems you need way more planning on how it will work before building it

Comment: I have one scene which will be a zoomed out view of the whole map and then seperate scenes for the different buildings, as the scenes for the buildings would have more details and animations than the zoomed out scene

Comment: I could use just one scene and change the camera position, add the animations and change the building's looks but I feel like that'd get very messy and it'll probably have a high change of messing up